# OAuth token REST call with another REST call

Tags: rest, oauth

Want to use REST API call based on other REST API call's response. For instance, REST GET OAuth token API Call returns Bearer token. How to use this token value for accessing the  particular resource using another REST GET API call.  Can we use as aggregator service?

Answer (score 0):

> How to use this token value for accessing the particular resource
>   using another REST GET API call

As the API is secured using OAuth2 , Access token (Bearer token) which is retrieved from the token API call needs to be passed in the header of the GET API call to access the resource.

Simple example of making that Rest call in Java  :

```
String Url = "http://www.testme.com/api/";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    //setting the headers 
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token_value); 
    //set more header value if required

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

    //executing the GET call
    HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(Url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

    //retrieving the response
    System.out.println("Response"+ response.getBody());
```